# How did commercial GBA games sample the button state?

Tags: nintendo, interrupt, game-boy-advance

For the GBA, I am under the impression that there are two ways to detect a button event:

- Enable IRQs and set up a handler for the button event
- Get a button's state (via the input bitmap) during the vblank period

Which of these two techniques was typically used, and why? What factors would lead a game developer to choose one technique over the other, if neither one of them is "the one right way"?

Did this also apply to older Nintendo handhelds like the GB/GBC, and newer ones like the NDS?

Comment: Both, as it's up to each developer what fits the situation in his ha game. There is neither a law nor a programming inquisition enforcing it. You may want to ask for a specific game.

Comment: @Raffzahn I've updated my question to ask more generally what factors determine which technique would be used. As for specific games, let's say games like: Crazy Taxy: Catch a Ride, Pokemon Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald, The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past. Or might they all be different?

Comment: Personal preference, game structure, libraries, pick your favourite one. Checking at a certain point in frame code will be most easy for simple games, while an interrupt handler comes easy when building a/on a more sophisticated framework.

Comment: Could even be both. IRQs for things where you want to be sure you count every button press and checking the state during the vblank for things like controlling character motion on a world map where you just care about whether the button is held at the moment when it's time to increment the world clock. I know that if you run the PC game Evoland under a version of Wine where you have to switch its runtime (which I remember being AIR or EXE-exported Flash) to software rendering to get it to run, it'll chug and your character will "over-walk" proportional to how long you held the button.

Comment: @ssokolow PC games handle it much differently than a console game (it's usually either always interrupts in the case of PS/2 keyboard, or kHz-level polling for a USB keyboard).

Comment: @forest My point was to demonstrate a situation which would have benefited from a hybrid of event-handling and state-checking approaches. I used a PC game as an example specifically *because* consoles have that predictable architecture that makes it difficult for such a problem to surface in anything polished. (Use event handling for D-Pad and you risk over-walking. Use state checking for menu nav or attacks and you risk missing button presses.)

Comment: @ssokolow Ah I see. I guess there's also issues like debouncing code being unnecessary if you're using vblanks (I dunno if the GBA has hardware debouncing or not. I know the NDS doesn't).

Comment: @forest note the USB controller polls, not the OS, AFAIK